# After Pressing (x) Closes the ActiveForm But its Process is still Running

Tags: c#, process, formclosing

**Hello**
So i have this weird problem [never faced like it before] .
it is Probably Because of a loop that i have which is like that :

```
while (chkDefault.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
{
    ValueOfX.Text = Convert.ToString( mem.ReadFloat( xGet ) );
    ValueOfY.Text = Convert.ToString( mem.ReadFloat( yGet ) );
    ValueOfZ.Text = Convert.ToString( mem.ReadFloat( zGet ) );
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

this loop is made after a button is clicked :

```
private void Start_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
```

PS : The process keeps running  even after closing the form (x) **ONLY** if  i clicked the button "Start" .

I also tried this  :

```
private void Form1_FormClosed (object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Process Proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("myFormProcess")[0];
    Proc.Close();
}
```

but nothing seems To work ... I added a messageBox Form1_FormClosed to see if it actualy works after closing the form and YES it promped the message .
But did not Close the process .

Comment: So many things wrong here. First cut the loop and use the checkbox checked event. Secondly i wish the process stop you are using is not for your current application.

Comment: what is ReadFloat method doing? are you creating any threads ? if there is any foreground thread active then the process won't shutdown.

Comment: If you have an infinite loop, you should just have a flag that stops it, i.e. set chkDefault.checked = false on form close.  Alternatively, while most don't recommend this, you can do Environment.Exit(0); to kill your program. Though, i would say be careful with that.

Comment: Haha , alright i just solved it by adding  :
            `chkDefault.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;`
just out of curiousity :
Why it does not close its own process ?

Comment: @SelmanGenç nop that method only read a float value from memory .. No threads have been created , I solved it tho Thanks .

Comment: @Hack why would i be carefull with it ? Please  Explain a lil bit .

Comment: @SaadAmrani  Environment.exit often times doesn't allow for cleanup to occur.  If it is called it abruptly kills the application without giving it the chance to clean up resources.  Basically, you should only use it when you know you don't need anything else to complete.

Comment: @SaadAmrani  :) just noticed your question under my comment.  When you click the (X) on a window, it doesn't actually tell the application to close, it just closes the window and allows the application to continue. Your loop continues running, so that thread never stops and the application essentially can't/won't stop when it has an active thread.

Comment: @Hack thank you !! Bless u .